# Support for Multi-Dimensional Arrays in QF_AUFBV?

Tags: z3, smt

I am currently working on code that translates a "path" through a C program into the corresponding SMT query to test the feasibility of this path. I have working code that create a SMT-LIB v1.2 query, and that uses Z3 2.11 and the QF_AUFBV logic to solve the query. I am currently porting this code over to Z3 4.3, to take advantage of any speed advances that may have happened since then, especially since my former code seems to take a long time (around 22 minutes) on a query that merely assigns 24 values to a three-dimensional array and checks the value of a certain location in the array.

However, it seems that the QF_AUFBV logic (as of the SMT-LIB v2.0 standard) no longer supports multi-dimensional arrays, or rather arrays whose values are also arrays (potentially deeper). Once I take out the line "(set-logic QF_AUFBV)" from my query, Z3 4.3 is able to process the query, but it still takes a long time.

I was wondering if anyone knew why support for multi-dimensional arrays was stopped in the SMT-LIB v2.0 standard, and what alternative logics I could use. I was also wondering what logic Z3 was anyway using when I took out the line that specified the QF_AUFBV theory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SMT-LIB standard never had support for multi-dimensional arrays. Z3 could process them, but they were not part of the standard. SMT-LIB 1.0 is a very restrictive format, that is why Z3 had several extensions for accommodating user needs. On the other hand, SMT-LIB 2.0 is a very rich input format and fixes the main issues users had with SMT-LIB 1.0. In Z3 4.x, when the logic is specified in the input file, Z3 tries to be compliant with the SMT-LIB 2.0 standard. When the `set-logic` is removed, all Z3 specific extensions are enabled.

As you described, an array sorrt `(Array I1 I2 R)` can be encoded as `(Array I1 (Array I2 R))`.

Regarding performance, Z3 3.x and 4.x do not have performance improvements for the array theory. They have many improvements for bit-vectors, but they are not available when the problem mixes arrays and bit-vectors. A new array theory is in TODO list, but nobody in the Z3 team is currently working on that.

Comment: Ah, thanks, Leonardo. Does the SMT-LIB v2.0 standard have support for multi-dimensional arrays in the QF_AUFBV theory? This didn't seem to be the case.

One potential fix I was thinking of using -- which would still allow me to use the QF_AUFBV theory -- was to concatenate the indices.

Comment: No, the QF_AUFBV theory does not support multidimensional arrays. Concatenating the indices is a solution, but it may make the problem harder to solve. For example, `j == w and a[i][j] != a[i][w]` is unsatisfiable, in this encoding, a solver can prove that without using any theory combination (only the array theory is needed). The formula `j == w and a[concat(i, j)] != a[concat(i, w)]` is also unsat, but the solvers for arrays and bit-vectors need to "interact" with each other.

Comment: All right, thanks for the explanation! I'm currently working with arrays of bit-vectors, so it seems like I'm constrained to the QF_AUFBV theory, but it's good to know the limitations.